# why can't I find my own installed artifact in eclipse search dialog?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I use `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=ojdbc -DartifactId=ojdbc -Dversion=6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgeneratePom=true` to install `ojdbc6.jar` to my local repository, the result of this command is `build success` and the `ojdbc6.jar` is copied to local respository,  then I try to add dependency in pom.xml, I click `add...` button in pom Dependencies panel, type `ojdbc` in input field and search, I can't find my own `ojdbc` artifact I just installed in searching results, so what should I do to search out my own `ojdbc` artifact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rebuild or update the index of your local repository in the `Maven Repository View` which is shown as follows :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea: Does the command line Maven and the Eclipse Maven use the same local repository/configuration?

And I don't exactly know if the search works for the local repository. So I would try to add the `<dependency>` for `ojdbc` manually and see if this works.

Comment: command line maven and eclipse maven use the same local repo and configuration. I try to add `<dependency>` in pom.xml, it works.

Comment: @hiway Maybe eclipse hasn't refreshed the local repo index. Maybe it's switched to offline in the configuration, or any other configuration is wrong there. I've just tested this on Juno SR2, it worked for me even without restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to `Reindex` by using the following step: -

1. Go to `Window` ----> `Preferences`.
2. At the `Preferences windows`, select `Maven` ----> `User Settings`
3. At the `Right hand panel`, click `Reindex` button.

I hope this may help.